# Concat Error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to concat datasets one with names of all the columns and one with same column names but not all of them. While trying to do so i.e while using concat I'm getting an error Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.
I have managed to make both the datasets column names exactly equal to each other too. Please help me.

```
Merged_Data = pd.concat([Merged_Data,df])
```

Comment: How about `Merged_Data = pd.concat([Merged_Data,df], ignore_index=True) `?

Comment: No this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You probably have duplicated columns, that is, columns with the same name